# Create a Picker that returns a String

Tags: swift, xcode, swiftui, picker

`Hello everyone`

I am creating a form that allows me to modify the data of @EnvironmentObject variable.

Therefore, I would like to be able to create a Picker that returns a String. However, after many unsuccessful attempts, I have the impression that a Picker cannot return a String.

Anyone would have an idea for a Picker that returns a String (maybe through UIKit ?).

Here's my code :

```swift
struct UserStruct {
    var firstName: String
    var lastName: String
    var birthDate: Int
    var city: String
    var postalCode: Int
    var street: String
    var streetCode: String
    var country: String
}

class User: ObservableObject {
   @Published var userProfile = UserStruct()
 // Other stuff here
}


// Then in my FormView: 
 // I declare the object as @EnvironmentObject
  @EnvironmentObject var userStore: User

 // I declare an array which contains all the country for the picker
  let country = ["France", "Russie", "USA"]


// In my var body: some View... 
// Trying to change the value of country of the userStore object
Picker(selection: $userStore.userProfile.country, label: Text("Make a choice")) {
  ForEach(0 ..< country.count) { index in
     Text(self.country[index]).tag(index)
  }
```

Thank you all for your help.

Answer (score 0):

you could try something like this:

```
let country = ["France", "Russie", "USA"]
@State var countrySelection = 0 

            Picker(selection: Binding(get: {
            self.countrySelection
        }, set: { newVal in
            self.countrySelection = newVal
            self.userStore.userProfile.country = self.country[self.countrySelection]
        }), label: Text("Make a choice")) {
            ForEach(0 ..< country.count) { index in
                Text(self.country[index]).tag(index)
            }
        }
```